# Getting Undefined Error while doing a Cypher csv import query

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, cypher

I am importing data from a csv file to  neo4j.
This is my query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS 
FROM "http://domain.com/file.csv"
AS line
CREATE(dir:Dir{ name:line.dname,id:line.din , comp_cin:line.in})
```

This csv file has over 100000 records.
I am inserting this query by neo4j browser and getting Error:Undefined-Undefined

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this could be a memory issue.

You may want to start by adding `USING PERIODIC COMMIT` before your `LOAD CSV`. That should chunk your commits and help keep heap usage down.

Here's the [relevant section](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#load-csv-importing-large-amounts-of-data) in the documentation, the surrounding topics should be helpful as well.